# Create array in PHP from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I think that I may be over trying things with little sleep but I am having problems creating arrays from mysql queries. I have a query like so:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM vehicles ORDER BY id");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $description = $row['description'];
    $description = strtoupper($description);
    $id = $row['id'];
}
```

I want it to create an array like so:

```
$v[1] = "Myarray1";
```

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
$v[ $row['id']] = $row;
```

Do I have to query like this:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){}
```

and if I do, how I do create the array as I need it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your code failed, *outright*. You need to check for errors and it will tell you *exactly* what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

At no point are you creating an array here. In your loop you are simply modifying some variables that in the context you posted I cannot reason on.

If all you need, no data filtering whatsoever this will do:

```
$list = Array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
   $list[] = $row;
}
```

[] basically 'appends' in PHP, it is an ugly mechanism but it works.

If you want to access rows per primary key ( `id` in your case I think ) then simply replace `[]` with `[$row["id"]]`

Comment: I'd take another look at their code and the api used.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You mean the mysql(i) part? I'd discourage using both API's normally, but it is not his question.

Comment: *"I'd discourage using both API's normally"* - Kind of... however, the thing is here is that the `mysql_` api does not intermix with any other than its own. *"but it is not his question"* - No, but it's part of the problem.

Comment: Plus, that should have been part of your answer to mention that they can't mix that different api with a `mysqli_` connection. People can't and should not rely on comments given.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure of the end result you're looking for. But if you want to access the results as $row['column'], where 'column' is a column name in your MySQL database, then you need to use mysql_fetch_assoc. I think this example will help:

```
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
   $v[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

**$v[1]['description']** is the data in the column description for the record with an id=1

Comment: This will not work, I hope you realize that and have looked at their query's api.

Comment: Plus the use of the added `()` around the loop should be removed.

Comment: Of course it works. it's also mentioned as part of the other answer here. The extra parentheses are to confirm that you want to do an assignment in an if statement. if (a=3) will generate a warning. if ((a=3)) will not.

Comment: It won't work, they're using the `mysqli_` api and you're telling them to use the `mysql_` api. Those different apis do not intermix.